# trying to print largest value of the array..but printing garbage

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

Hey i am trying to print largest element in an array using function and pointers. Below is my code but its printing garbage value. Please help.

```
void findmax(int arr[],int,int*);
void findMax(int arr[], int n, int* pToMax)
{
    if (n <= 0) 
        return;      // no items, no maximum!

int max = arr[0];
pToMax = &arr[0];

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] > max)
    {
         max = arr[i];
         pToMax = (arr+i);
    }
}
}       
int main()
{
    int nums[4] = { 5, 3, 15, 6 };
    int *ptr;
    findMax(nums, 4, ptr);
    printf("The maximum is at address %u\n", ptr);
    printf("It's at index %d\n",ptr - nums);
    printf("Its value is %d\n", *ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `int *pToMax` in `findMax(int arr[], int n, int* pToMax)` and

calling as `findMax(nums, 4, ptr);` you just pass `ptr` as a value.

The updated value won't be reflected after function exits.

You need to use `**pToMax`

to save address.

```
void findMax(int arr[], int n, int** pToMax)
{
    if (n <= 0) 
        return;      // no items, no maximum!

int max = arr[0];
*pToMax = &arr[0]; //Store base address

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] > max)
    {
         max = arr[i];
         *pToMax = (arr+i); //Store max address
    }
}

}
```

call using

`findMax(nums, 4, &ptr);`

Comment: yeah did it your way but its printing the first element as maximum. Also *ptomax will store value (as pointer works) so why storing address?

Comment: don't you think passing ptr is like passing address...coz after all its a pointer and ptr will pass the address itself. If i am wrong then please explain.

Comment: Hey, thanks man. can you please give me some links or sources from where i can clear my concepts of pointers.